# Characterization of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of the form $X+Y$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

The following comes from the mathematical tripos exam at Cambridge:

Let $X,Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and define $X+Y = \{x+y : x \in X, y \in Y\}$

Prove or disprove each of the following:
(i) If each of $X,Y$ is closed and bounded, $X+Y$ is closed and bounded.
(ii) If $X$ is bounded and closed, and $Y$ is closed, $X+Y$ is closed.
(iii) If $X$ and $Y$ are closed, $X+Y$ is closed.
(iv) If $X$ is open and $Y$ is closed, $X+Y$ is open.

Attempt:
(i) If $X,Y$ are closed and bounded, then $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus X$ and $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus Y$ are open and unbounded. We need show $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus(X+Y)$ is also open and unbounded. Given any element $x+y \in X+Y$ we construct $B_{\tilde{\epsilon}}(x+y)$ in a natural way. Since there exists $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ so that $B_{\epsilon_1}(x) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \setminus X$ and $B_{\epsilon_2} (y) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \setminus Y$, we see that $$B_{\epsilon_1}(x) + B_{\epsilon_2}(y) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \setminus  (X+Y)$$
Let $\tilde{\epsilon}  = \min\{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\}$. By the triangle inequality, we have $$B_{\tilde{\epsilon}} (x+y) \subset \mathbb{R}^n \setminus (X+Y)$$ so that this set is open. The fact that both $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus X$ and $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus Y$ are unbounded implies that they are unbounded in at least one coordinate. We have two cases:
Suppose $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus X$ is unbounded in $i$, $(x_1,\ldots x_i, \ldots, x_n)$ and suppose $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus Y$ is unbounded in $j \neq i$. Then, clearly the sum $(x_1+y_1,\ldots, x_i + y_i, \ldots, x_j + y_j, \ldots, x_n+y_n)$ is unbounded. Now, suppose both sets are unbounded in $i$. Then, call the $A$ set of $x_i$ and $B$ the set of $y_i$. Either $A = (a,\infty)$ or $A=(-\infty,a)$ or $A=(-\infty,a) \cup (a,\infty)$ for some $a$. Likewise for $B$ with some $b$. Checking all of these cases, we see that $A+B$ is unbounded and therefore $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus (X+Y)$ is open and unbounded and so $X+Y$ is closed and bounded.  We conclude that, for $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ closed and bounded, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$$ is also closed and bounded.

(ii) Using the same argument as (i) (I think?) we can conclude that $X+Y$ is closed.

Is it valid to do this component-wise and use the facts that $\sup(\pi_i(X+Y) = \sup(\pi_i(X)) + \sup(\pi_i(Y))$ and $\inf(\pi_i(X+Y)) = \inf(\pi_i(X)) + \inf(\pi_i(Y))$ and thus the sum is bounded above and below by $[\inf(\pi_i(X+Y)), \sup(\pi_i(X+Y)]$ and since $X$ and $Y$ are closed, we have $$\pi_i(X+Y) = [\inf(\pi_i(X+Y)), \sup(\pi_i(X+Y)]$$

Where $\pi_i: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is the canonical projection onto $i$th coordinate. That is, each $i$th level-cut is closed, if we fix the other coordinates.

(iv) Not sure where to begin.

Any hints would be wonderful on all four parts. I'm pretty sure Bolzano-Weierstrass would simplify (i) quite a bit, but I wanted to try to use the closed argument in (i) in (ii) and (iii).

Comment: For part (iv), the example you give is not actually a counterexample: $X + Y = (-1,\infty)$, not $Y$. I believe that (iv) is actually true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slick solution to (i) using compactness: simply observe that if $X,Y$ are compact then so is $X\times Y$. Then $f(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous, so $f(X\times Y)=X+Y$ is also compact (as the continuous image of a compact set).

You can get (ii) by using subsequential convergence of compact sets.

(iii) is false, as is seen by the example $X=\mathbb Z$ and $Y=\{n+\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$

(iv) is really easy and doesn't even need $Y$ to be closed, just write
$$
X+Y=\bigcup_{y\in Y}X+\{y\}.
$$
Then translates of open sets are open, and arbitrary unions of open sets are open so you're done.

Comment: This is wonderful. I must ask though, is my remarkably less-slick solution for (i) and (ii) still correct?

Comment: I didn't quite follow your proof of (i) and also I didn't see a proof of (ii), since it seemed like you were using boundedness of both $X$ and $Y$. But what you're doing should work also.

Comment: for (ii) I meant the same argument, as the same argument in (i) which only used the fact that these sets were closed. Ergo, there must be something wrong, for then (iii) would also be proven. Could you help deduce an error? Also, could you elaborate a bit on how to use sequential compactness for (ii)? This was my initial idea but I didn't quite see how to follow through with it.

Comment: I think the mistake is when you're constructing $B_{\tilde \epsilon}(x+y)$. It might not be entirely contained in that set.

Comment: I see. What about (ii)? That is, could you elaborate?

Comment: To show that it is closed, it suffices to show that the set contains its limit points. Now write down a convergent sequence in $X+Y$; the limit of the points in $Y$ will still belong to $Y$, and (applying compactness) allows you to pass to a suitable subsequence to get the points in $X$ converging with the same indices.

Comment: could you add the details of this to your answer? If so, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Do you mean something of the sort: if $\{x_n+y_n\} \to \tilde{x} + \tilde{y}$ then there exists a subsequence of $\{y_n\}$ so that $\{y_{n_k}\} \to \tilde{y}$ and since $\{x_{n_k}\}$ must converge in $X$ for some subsequence, $\{x_{n_j}\}$ we take the intersection of the two sets of indices to get a subsequence converging to $\tilde{x} + \tilde{y}$? Something like this? I don't think I'm phrasing the first part right..

Comment: Do you mean something of the sort: if $\{x_n+y_n\} \to \tilde{x} + \tilde{y}$ then $\{y_n\} \to \tilde{y}$ since $Y$ is closed and since $\{x_{n}\}$ must converge in $X$ for some subsequence, $\{x_{n_k}\}$ to get a subsequence converging to $\tilde{x} + \tilde{y}$? Something like this? I don't think I'm phrasing the first part right..